# Array of objects vs arrays of object's properties − which is more efficient?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object

Which is faster and consumes less memory — an array of objects with a set of properties or all of the object's properties as arrays?

I'm making a 2d tile game and the world consists of tiles, so I create a separate instance of `Tile` class for each tile, and some people say it could be faster if I used arrays of tiles' properties instead. I'd like to see the difference with my own eyes, but the game is too complex at this point to rewrite the code.

**Update:** I found some time to test both options, and with insignificant memory and cpu differences, array of objects wins for being so much easier to work with (code readability + debugging simplicity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably depends on your array creation and access patterns; but, as a rule of thumb, I would not expect those two approaches to have significant performance differences. If you really think it might be a performance issue, the only way to be sure is to implement both, profile the program, and compare results.

Having an array of `Tile` would likely be much simpler, straight-forward code, so go with that. If you have actual performance problems, profile to find the expensive sections of the code.

Comment: I would say simple, readable code is better than the constant time performance change (if any).

Answer (score 2):

From a memory usage standpoint, an array of properties will consume less memory. From a practical standpoint though, using the array of objects adds a layer of abstraction that allows for easier debugging and the ability to easily modify code to add in new properties.

Comment: If all the tile objects are there already and referenced by something else, creating a new array of objects and referencing the same tiles, will not "consume more memory" than an "array of properties". This is because the Original Poster explained that `Tile` was a `class` (as opposed to `struct`). The new array will therefore only contain _references_ to the same old instances (`class` implies reference type). An array of references, under these circumstances, will consume very little "extra" memory (the tile objects already being in existence).